# Smartcardio deadlock

Tags: java, api, smartcard

Profiling my application (using yourkit) i see a deadlock into java api (frozen for 7h 23m 14 sec).

This is what the profiler print:

```
Frozen threads found (potential deadlock)

It seems that the following threads have not changed their stack for more than 10 seconds.
These threads are possibly (but not necessarily!) in a deadlock or hung.

Thread-13 <--- Frozen for at least 7h 23m 14 sec
sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardListReaders(long)
sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCTerminals.list(CardTerminals$State)
javax.smartcardio.CardTerminals.list()
xxx.xxxxxx.cardreader.CardReader.run()
```

And this is how i use the api (i extract only usefull code)

```
 public void run() {
    protocolArr = {"T=0", "T=1"}
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);             

            TerminalFactory terminalFactory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
            List<CardTerminal> terminalList = terminalFactory.terminals().list();   
            for(CardTerminal terminal : terminalList) {
                Card card = null;                   
                // establish a connection with the card
                for(String protocol : protocolArr) {
                    try {
                        card = terminal.connect(protocol);
                        break;
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                if(card == null)
                    continue;                   
                // The card is valorized                    
                CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();                   
                // SN request
                byte[] byteArr = new byte[5];                   
                // FFh FCh 01h 00h 00h 
                byteArr[0] = (byte) 0xFF;
                byteArr[1] = (byte) 0xFC;
                byteArr[2] = 0x00; // 00h : ATQA + SN + SAK
                byteArr[3] = 0x00;
                byteArr[4] = 0x00;                  
                ResponseAPDU r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(byteArr));                    
                // 44h 03h 04h 26h 47h 09h 48h E8h 10h 20h 90h 00h (example) 
                //      ATQA = 44h 03h 04h 
                //      SN = 26h 47h 09h 48h E8h 10h (7 bytes) 
                //      SAK = 20h                   
                byte[] response = r.getBytes();                 
               // disconnect
                card.disconnect(false);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

has someone ever come across this problem and is there a fix/workaround?

Comment: Are you using javax.smartcardio on 64-bit Java on OS X? I got NULL dereference interrupts within CardTerminals.list(), but it’s possible for other undefined behavior to happen. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071532/reading-nfc-tag-using-java-smart-card-api-not-working-on-mac-os/

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the [`waitForChange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardTerminals.html#waitForChange%28long%29) method instead of polling the card terminals.

Note that `CardTerminals` is returned from `terminalFactory.terminals()`, so before you call `list()`.

Comment: Thanks, now i use waitForChange to optimize the code but i need to cycle sometimes cause in my application is possible that users remove and connect in other pc the card reader so i need to refresh the terminals

Comment: OK, but that should not be an event that needs to be recognized the microsecond that it occurs. Give `waitForChange` a timeout and check when the timeout is finished or when an event occurs.