# Smart Card detection with java

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcardio

i'm using the following code to test whether there is a smart card connected to computer or not

```
public static boolean verifySmartCardPresence() {
    boolean cardPresent = false;
    try {
        TerminalFactory tf = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        List<CardTerminal> terminals = tf.terminals().list();
        for (CardTerminal terminal : terminals) {
            if (terminal.isCardPresent()) {
                System.out.println(terminal);
                cardPresent = true;
            }
        }
        return cardPresent;
    } catch (CardException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

it works like a charm but when i'm unplug the smartcard and replug it without closing the program, it does not retrieve it anymore, it gives me exception just like there is no smart  card connected
what is the problem ?
[UPDATE]
this is the error log :

```
[10-04-2018 16:14:28.801] [ERROR][c.m.utils.CertificateUtils.verifySmartCardPresence(138)] - list() failed 
javax.smartcardio.CardException: list() failed
at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCTerminals.list(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at javax.smartcardio.CardTerminals.list(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at com.mar.utils.CertificateUtils.verifySmartCardPresence(CertificateUtils.java:130) ~[mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at com.mar.ws.impl.SignWSImpl.signData(SignWSImpl.java:58) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:350) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539) [mar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: SCARD_E_SERVICE_STOPPED
at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardListReaders(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: paste error log to the question

Comment: Is your issue same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921785/smartcard-terminal-removal-scard-e-no-service-cardexception)?

Comment: @vlp no sir, i'm facing this problem with all windows distribution (not only windows 8)